# Setting a default value of a variable to use if "read -t" timeout takes place

Tags: linux, shell

I'm trying to read user input which has a default value set but when I do a echo the data is not printed

```
#!/bin/sh
ROUTETOCOM="n"  
read -t 4 -p "Route data from Port? [y/n] : " ROUTETOCOM
echo $ROUTETOCOM
```

If the user dosen't key in any value within 4 seconds echo $ROUTETOCOM is not displaying 'n'
What is wrong with the script?

Comment: You are using BASH syntax in a CSH script

Comment: BTW, all-caps variable names are defined for variables with meaning to the OS or shell; application-defined variables should have lowercase names. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, fourth paragraph, keeping in mind that setting a shell variable overwrites any like-named environment variable.

Comment: @user1184100, ...btw, I took the liberty of switching from `#!/bin/csh` to `#!/bin/sh`, as the `shell` tag is specified for POSIX solutions unless otherwise given, and csh is not at all POSIX-compliant. That said, note that `read -p` itself is a bashism, and requires a more modern baseline shell than POSIX sh to guarantee support; `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/bin/ksh` is thus strongly recommended.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Suggested Workaround

If you want to apply a default, do that after the fact:

```
read -t 4 -p "Route data from Port? [y/n] : " route_toggle
: "${route_toggle:=n}"
```

See also the Bash-Hackers' Wiki [page on parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) -- particularly, the sections on [using a default value](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#use_a_default_value) or [assigning a default value](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#assign_a_default_value).

---

#### Explanation

The documentation for `read -t` follows (for bash 3.2):

> The `-t` option causes read to time out and return failure if a complete line
>     of input is not read within TIMEOUT seconds.  If the TMOUT variable is set,
>     its value is the default timeout.  The return code is zero, unless end-of-file
>     is encountered, read times out, or an invalid file descriptor is supplied as
>     the argument to -u.

Or, for bash 4.3:

> `-t timeout` - time out and return failure if a complete line of input is          not read within TIMEOUT seconds.  The value of the TMOUT
>                   variable is the default timeout.  TIMEOUT may be a
>                   fractional number.  If TIMEOUT is 0, read returns immediately,
>                   without trying to read any data, returning success only if
>                   input is available on the specified file descriptor.  The
>                   exit status is greater than 128 if the timeout is exceeded

No part of either version of this documentation expresses or implies that a timeout will not cause the value to be changed; the **only** guarantee is that the return code will not be zero in the event that a timeout takes place.

---